# Axios: Upload progress for multiple file uploads

Tags: javascript, file-upload, axios

Following https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html I've set up a file upload with progress bar.

However, I have `<input type="file" multiple>`, so the upload is inside a loop like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++)
{
    var config = {
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            var what = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
        }
    };
    axios.post(url, data, config)
        .then(function (response) {
    });                            
}
```

**The question is: How can I assign the upload progress (see `var what`) to the *corresponding* file?**

Everything I've tried didn't work:

- The callback function `onUploadProgress` apparently doesn't take any second argument: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config
- The injected `progressEvent` object doesn't contain any information about the uploaded file. Example:

  ```
  progress { target: XMLHttpRequestUpload, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 181914, total: 181914, currentTarget: XMLHttpRequestUpload, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false }
  ```
- The looping variable `i` is accessible in principle - however, it's always at the *last* position (since the loop has finished when `onUploadProgress` gets called during the upload)
- I couldn't figure out a way to access axios' `data` from inside `onUploadProgress`
- `this` refers to:

  ```
  XMLHttpRequestUpload { onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, ontimeout: null, onloadend: null }
  ```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Am I missing something here? You are inside a for loop and uploading one file at a time. That means that in every progressEvent you are already referring to the corresponding file. Could you add a listener to the progressEvent and print out its "total" value? I think you are already looking at the corresponding files. As a side note take the config out of the for loop you dont need to re-define it per file.

Comment: I'm also wondering how to achieve this. With jQuery, I've been using the "xhrFields" parameter, but I'm not sure if Axios has anything similar.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a function that return another decorated function with some Id as parameter.

Example:

```
const myUploadProgress = (myFileId) => (progress) => {
  let percentage = Math.floor((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total)
  console.log(myFileId)
  console.log(percentage)
}

for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
  var config = {
    onUploadProgress: myUploadProgress(files[i].id)
  };

  axios.post(url, data, config).then(function (response) {});                            
}
```

If you don't have ES6 you can do:

```
function myUploadProgress(myFileId) {
  return function(progress) {
    ...
  }
}
```

(I'm using a similar code on my project and it works like a charm)

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable scoping issue. In JavaScript `var` declares a variable in a *function* scope. There are a lot of potential solution, depending on which version of ES your target browser supports. I'll use the same function to demonstrate:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); }, i * 100);
```

Using `var` this will print out '5' 5 times. We want it to print out `0 1 2 3 4`.

If you have `Array#forEach`, you can use that since the closure creates a new function scope

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(i) { 
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); }, i * 100);
});
```

If you have access to `let`, `let` and `const` uses *block* scoping instead (ie. the variable is scoped to the nearest set of `{ ... }`).

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); }), i * 100);
}
```

If you don't have access to either of those, you can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). It's really ugly but it gets the job done.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
    (function() {
        var newI = i;
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log(newI); }, i * 100); 
    })();
}
```