# Vue - Progress bar for each upload

Tags: vue.js

My current progress bar is being shared by all the files, as a result the progress bar jumps back and forth. How do I separate the progress bar for each uploaded file?

```
submitFiles() {
  for( let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ) {
    if(this.files[i].id) {
      continue;
    }
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[i]);

    axios.post('/files/upload-file', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      onUploadProgress: function( progressEvent ) {
        this.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total ) * 100 ))
      }.bind(this)
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      this.files[i].id = data['data']['id'];
      this.files.splice(i, 1, this.files[i]);
      console.log('success');
      }.bind(this))
    .catch(function(data) {
      console.log('error');
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893946/axios-upload-progress-for-multiple-file-uploads) and I'm getting my desired result in the `console.log`. The only problem now is how do I store the value of `percentage` in my progress bar.

```
const myUploadProgress = (myFileId) => (progress) => {
  let percentage = Math.floor((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total)
  console.log(myFileId)
  console.log(percentage)
  }
  for( let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ) {
    var config = {
      onUploadProgress: myUploadProgress(this.files[i])
    }

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[i].name);

    axios.post('/files/upload-file', formData, config, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
```

Template:

```
 <v-progress-linear max="100" :value="??"></v-progress-linear>
```

Comment: Have you tried `files.map((v,i)=>{//dowhatever})` ?

Comment: I still haven't tried `files.map` I'll look into it on how to incorporate it in my code, thank you.